# IIS Node autostart on change and keep alive

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I am not sure if that's how it supposed to work, or I missed something.

On any changes I make, app stops, but seems like it never starts by its own. When I make a call to page it takes long time then errors and then when I repeat call it works fine.

So seems like to start it again I have to poke it with request?

Anyone is familiar with iisnode ?

Comment: iisnode is a dead project (almost two years), so what are you looking for?

Comment: but it works. Well I looked into PM2 to host node APIs, but I had big issues to make it robust. I couldn't make it not to stop when user is logging out from the server. And seems like it's not only me but just a nature of the pm2. Because on the server I have IIS something like iisnode seems like good solution. it has watcher, and starts whenever IIS is started. I am just surprised that here is no robust windows deployment for node.

Comment: Microsoft has stopped all its attempts on PHP/Python/NodeJS on Windows/IIS in favor of native Linux based solutions, so your "surprise" came a little bit late.

Answer (score 0):

You could try watchedFiles attribute on the iisnode element in your Web.config file. Using this, you can set IISNode to watch your config file(s) and whenever they change IISNode will recycle the site.

```
watchedFiles="*.js;*.hbs;web.config;routes\*;views\*;controllers\*;models\*"
```

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config